# Where does the 'Record a short screencast' save the file? (ctrl+alt+shift+R) 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04

I found the hotkey 'Record a short screencast' tied to ctrl+alt+shift+R, but I don't know where the screencast is saved.

Comment: go to `Files` and select `Recent` Right Click with the mouse on the file and then select `Open Item Location`. That will reveal where the files are saved to.

Comment: Check under `~/Videos`.

Answer (score 1):

It is saved in the 'videos' in the 'Home' folder. To identify the file: the file name starts with 'Screencast', will have a timestamp in it, and will have webm file extension.